# Add all distinct values of a column to an array

Tags: sql, presto

I'm trying to output the distinct values of a column into an array instead of `SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table` which would output 1 row per unique value. I am wanting to have just 1 row. I have tried a few method to do this but I keep ending up with the error:

> `syntax error: no viable alternative at input 'ARRAY_DISTINCT(SELECT'`.

```
SELECT
    ARRAY_DISTINCT(SELECT column_1 FROM table WHERE p = '2022-08-17') as column_distinct_values

'Where `p` is the partition
```

I have also tried the below method which yields the same error.

```
SELECT
    ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT column_1 FROM table WHERE p = '2022-08-17') as column_distinct_values

'Where `p` is the partition
```

**So the question is, what is the correct syntax/method to achieve this?**

---

Sample input/desired output

[image]

Comment: Any reason for not opening the documentation?

Comment: Thanks for that. I did and couldn't figure it out still. I guess I'm sTuPiD. @DavidדודוMarkovitz thanks again

Comment: Where did you look? Can you share a link?

Comment: Mostly here, I looked at a few other pages but mostly focused on this one. https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html

Comment: Almost. https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz it would have been so much more helpful if you would have just shared that instead of quizzing me lol. I also should have posted the link I used in the question. The joys of Stack

Comment: Fish, fishing rod, yada, yada, yada. I've noticed a rapid decline in the quality of SO in the last years, for both questions and answers. It seems everyone has turn to brainless zombies. We could have completed this discussion within 2 minutes, but people tends to post a question and then disappear for days/months/years. I have nomerous of beautiful solutions still waiting for the OP. The joy of Stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT column_1 FROM table WHERE p = '2022-08-17'` does not return an array, if you want to compact everything into one cell you can try `group by` with aggregation into array:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (val) AS (
    VALUES ('NORAM'),
    ('NORAM'),
    ('NORAM1')
)

-- query
select array_distinct(array_agg(val))
from dataset
group by true; -- fake grouping
```

Or

```sql
-- query
select array_agg(distinct val) 
from dataset 
group by true; -- fake grouping
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| [NORAM, NORAM1] |